# How to connect the wrapper to the plunker?

Tags: angular, plunker, papaparse

how to connect [ngx-papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-papaparse) to the plunker?
I added import:

```
import { PapaParseService } from 'ngx-papaparse';
```

- in my `app.ts` - don't work

http://embed.plnkr.co/5NxOmV4jkaCgwu0OaZRU/

Comment: have you tried `https://unpkg.com/ngx-papaparse@1.2.5/bundles/ngx-papaparse.umd.js`

Comment: yes, i added this in index.htm 
`<script scr="https://unpkg.com/ngx-papaparse@1.2.5/bundles/ngx-papaparse.umd.js"></script>    `

and config.js
`'ngx-papaparse': 'npm:ngx-papaparse@1.2.5/bundles/ngx-papaparse.umd.js'`

Comment: Change typescript version to 2.2.1. 2.5.3 doesn't emit parameters metadata

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/PkxS31FZjcJN9hnwwYIu?p=preview

Comment: yurzui, thank you very much